# Redirect using next in django even after taking multiple attempts to login

Tags: django

I am having this login view:

```
def login(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            email=request.POST['email']
            password=request.POST['password']
            user=auth.authenticate(email=email,password=password)

            if user is not None:
                auth.login(request, user)
                next_page = request.POST['next']
                if next_page != '':
                    return redirect(next_page)
                else:
                    return redirect('/')
            else:
                messages.info(request,"Email Password didn't match")
                return redirect('login')
        else:
            return render(request,"login.html")
```

In this if a user comes to a page where login is required then he is redirected to login page and when he logs in successfully he is redirected to the page where he came from. But the problem arises when the user does not login in first attempt(enters wrong email or password) then the login page reloads and then if he logs in successfully he isnt redirected to the page where he came from. How can I work this out so that no matter the number of attempts the user takes to login he is redirected to the same page from where he came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are using POST to get the next url and is redirecting. So whenever the login fails and redirects to the login page `next` has to be set in the form.

By default django has this feature of redirecting to the next page after login: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-raw-way)

```py
redirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.LOGIN_URL, request.path))
```

You could generate the URL and pass it to `reverse`. You don't need to create another URL pattern for this. The next url has to be passed as a GET argument in the login link.

```py
from django.urls import reverse
from urllib.parse import urlencode

def login(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            #code
            next = request.POST['next']

            if user is not None:
                auth.login(request, user)
                if next_page != '':
                    return redirect(next_page)
                else:
                    return redirect('/')
            else:
                messages.info(request,"Email Password didn't match")
                login_url = reverse('login') # get the login url
                query_string =  urlencode({'next': next})
                url = '{}?{}'.format(login_url, query_string) # create the url
                return redirect(url)
        else:
            return render(request,"login.html")
```

Comment: I am using a custom user model so thats Y I am using custom login view

Comment: Its giving me this error: `NameError at /login/
name 'reverse' is not defined`

Comment: @rohitbumrah import reverse

Comment: `NoReverseMatch at /login/
Reverse for 'None' not found. 'None' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Comment: on incorrect login this url opens up: `http://localhost:8000/login/?next=None`

Comment: can you please add the view which you are trying to access and redirects to login

Comment: `<a href="{% url 'login' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Add to Cart</a></button>`  I am using this is template for users trying to add to cart without logging in

Comment: and this in my login form: `<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.GET.next }}">`

Comment: Do you see  login?next=url in browser when you click add to cart ?. If so, you will be able to access this value using GET `next = request.GET.get('next')`. verify this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220486/discussion-between-achuthvarghese-and-rohit-bumrah).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted to know can something like this be done so that If a user doesnt have an account and from the login pages goes to signup page and from there he is redirected to the same page